# fixing ntfs partition after ddrescue

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, ntfs, ddrescue

I had some really slow disk access and determined my disk was unhealthy. I was still able to see file contents and use most of the drive contents in Windows, but a few files were inaccessible. This was not the system disk.

I used ddrescue to recover the failing drive directly to a new, larger drive. This seemed successful with only about 1.5 MB unrecoverable. I was able to use ddru_ntfsfindbad to determine the affected bad file names from the new drive.

Now when in Windows Disk Management, it lists several partitions on the new drive, none matching the size of the original.  The original drive had a single NTFS partition.

I can't even get the original drive to spin up anymore. So if the data on the new drive is usable, I want to make sure I don't hose it up. I'm willing to buy another drive if its there is risk of damaging the data by recovering the partition.

What is the best way to get Windows to recognize a healthy partition? Do I need to run fdisk? Should I run chkdsk on the volume? What should my next steps be?

Comment: Since the new drive is spinning, before you do anything on it, create a disk image for it. Then start experimenting on it.